# REST Api returning different object names for the same object, how to handle with RestSharp?

Tags: c#, json, rest, restsharp, qualtrics

I'm programming a C# implementation for the [Qualtrics API](https://survey.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/ControlPanel/docs.php) (v 2.5) using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/). When calling the method [getUserIds](https://survey.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/ControlPanel/docs.php#getUserIds_2.5), it returns a list of users in JSON format (see the example output below).

**The problem/question I face is** that for each user object (the list of objects under `Result`) it generates a different id, starting with `URH_`. When using [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) it assumes ofcourse that it's always a different class, while in fact it's absolutely the same one as you can see in the output, and as is stated in the documentation of the api. **How can I best resolve this - so that I can make a class `UserData` that I can reuse?** Because now I obviously always see these random `URH_` prefixed classes in each response.

NOTE: I was thinking I could try to massage the response first, and when I get the response replace each `URH_` prefixed object under the root `Result` object with a `"UserData"` string - but I feel this is breaking the rules a bit, and thought the community would have a better solution?

---

*Below is the raw JSON output (note that I removed sensitive information)*:

```
{"Meta":{"Status":"Success","Debug":""},"Result":{"URH_3wpA9pxGbE0c7Xu":{"DivisionID":null,"UserName":"user.name@domain.com","UserFirstName":"x","UserLastName":"x","UserAccountType":"UT_4SjjZmbPphZGKDq","UserEmail":"x.x@x.x","UserAccountStatus":"Active"},"URH_57vQr8MVXgpcPUo":{"DivisionID":"DV_XXXXXXXX","UserName":"jxxxx@xx.xxx","UserFirstName":"X","UserLastName":"X","UserAccountType":"UT_BRANDADMIN","UserEmail":"xxxx@xxg.xxx","UserAccountStatus":"Active"},"URH_6ujW1EP0QJOUaoI":{"DivisionID":"DV_XXXXXXXYZ","UserName":"x.xckx@xxx.xyz","UserFirstName":"x","UserLastName":"x","UserAccountType":"UT_XXXXXABCD","UserEmail":"c.c@cc.com","UserAccountStatus":"Active"}}}
```

*This is what I get when generating a model using [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)*:

```
public class Meta
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Debug { get; set; }
}

public class URH3wpA9pxGbE0c7Xu
{
    public object DivisionID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
    public string UserLastName { get; set; }
    public string UserAccountType { get; set; }
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    public string UserAccountStatus { get; set; }
}

public class URH57vQr8MVXgpcPUo
{
    public string DivisionID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
    public string UserLastName { get; set; }
    public string UserAccountType { get; set; }
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    public string UserAccountStatus { get; set; }
}

public class URH6ujW1EP0QJOUaoI
{
    public string DivisionID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
    public string UserLastName { get; set; }
    public string UserAccountType { get; set; }
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    public string UserAccountStatus { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public URH3wpA9pxGbE0c7Xu URH_3wpA9pxGbE0c7Xu { get; set; }
    public URH57vQr8MVXgpcPUo URH_57vQr8MVXgpcPUo { get; set; }
    public URH6ujW1EP0QJOUaoI URH_6ujW1EP0QJOUaoI { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Meta Meta { get; set; }
    public Result Result { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's simple - just use `Dictionary<string, UserData>` generic type for `Result` field:

```
public class Response
{
    public Meta Meta { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, UserData> Result { get; set; }
}

public class Meta
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Debug { get; set; }
}

public class UserData
{
    public string DivisionID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
    public string UserLastName { get; set; }
    public string UserAccountType { get; set; }
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    public string UserAccountStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out and get back to you!

Comment: Just to confirm, worked for me a-ok this way. Stupid I didn't come up with this myself, new to consuming REST API's ;)...